# Signal CGI output is finished before program exits

Tags: c, apache, web-applications, cgi

I am trying to get an optimisation working more reliably for a CGI program written in C.

The application does synchronous writes to disc and what I would like is for these to be done after the CGI output is finished.  I initially thought this was as simple as closing / reopening the stdin/stdout/stderr streams, and indeed this worked absolutely beautifully on a number of servers - I was getting user response out in milliseconds even when there was a couple of seconds of disc writes queued up.

Unfortunately I'm now experiencing a problem on a couple of servers.  As soon as the CGI program closes stdout, it receives a terminate signal from Apache.  A couple of seconds later, it gets a hard kill.  Calling `setsid()` seems to have no effect on this.

Is there another way to tell Apache it should send output to the client, without ending the CGI program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to do this when using mod_cgi and a single process.  It's heavy on resources, but a generally accepted method of achieving this is called a double fork. It goes something like this:

```
pid_t kid, grandkid;
if ((kid = fork())) {
    waitpid(kid, null, 0);
}
else if ((grandkid = fork())) {
    exit(0);
}
else {
    // code here
    // do something long lasting
    exit(0);
}
```

[Adapted from this PERL code](http://modperlbook.org/html/10-2-4-Avoiding-Zombie-Processes.html#pmodperl-CHP-10-EX-18)

Comment: Regrettably I'm forced to accept this is the right answer.  Forking the process takes too much resource considering I'm trying to do an optimisation here!  I'm looking into moving away from CGI instead now.

Answer (score 2):

Just throwing out ideas there.  The current setup looks like this

```
+------------+            +------------+
|    CGI     |----------->|   Apache   |
|  Program   |<-----------|   Server   |    
+------------+            +------------+
```

How about something like this

```
+------------+    +------------+    +------------+
|   Daemon   |--->|    CGI     |--->|   Apache   |
|  Program   |<---|  Passthru  |<---|   Server   |
+------------+    +------------+    +------------+
```

Basically, move all of the functionality of your current program into a daemon that is launched once at startup. Then create a tiny passthru program for Apache to launch via CGI. The passthru program attaches itself to the daemon using IPC, either shared memory, or sockets.  Everything that the passthru program receives on stdin, it forwards to the daemon. Everything that the passthru program receives from the daemon, it forwards to Apache on stdout. That way Apache can launch/kill the passthru program as it pleases, without affecting what you're trying to do on the backend.

Answer (score 2):

An option to consider is:

1. CGI program generates output to Apache.
2. Before closing standard output, it forks.
3. The parent process closes its standard output and then uses one of the emergency exit functions (`_exit()` or `_Exit()` or one of their relatives) to bail out.  This avoids flushing the other I/O streams.
4. The child processes closes file descriptor 1 with `close()` — it avoids using `fclose()` because the parent is writing to standard output.
5. The child process then deals with the rest of the writing work.

You might need to isolate the child from its parent by setting its process group.  Apache can only send the child process a signal via the process group (because it doesn't know the PID of the child process), so by disassociating from the original process group, your child process becomes immune to Apache sending it signals.

Another option worth considering has the parent do the work, then fork.  The parent process doesn't flush standard output; it just uses the emergency exit function.  The child process isolates itself from the parent, and then closes standard output with `fclose()`, flushing any pending output.  Apache sees the file is closed and continues on its merry way.  The child process then does its cleanup.  Again, setting the child into its own process group is crucial.  The advantage of this is that the output is not closed until after the child has isolated itself, so Apache shouldn't be able to use timing coincidences to send a signal to the child (Apache's grandchild).  You might even just isolate the process in its own process group before forking…that also eliminates the window of vulnerability for the child.  You shouldn't do that isolation until you're about to fork and exit, though; otherwise, you defeat the protection mechanisms that Apache provides.

---

#### Example code

Here's a simulation of what you might do, in a source file `playcgi.c` compiled to a program `playcgi`:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void err_exit(const char *fmt, ...);
static void be_childish(void);
static void be_parental(pid_t pid, int fd[2]);

int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    if (pipe(fd) != 0)
        err_exit("pipe()");
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        err_exit("fork()");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        be_childish();
    }
    else
        be_parental(pid, fd);
    return 0;
}

static void be_parental(pid_t pid, int fd[2])
{
    close(fd[1]);
    char buffer[1024];
    int nbytes;
    while ((nbytes = read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, nbytes);
    kill(-pid, SIGTERM);
    struct timespec nap = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 10 * 1000 * 1000 };
    nanosleep(&nap, 0);
    int status;
    pid_t corpse = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
    if (corpse <= 0)
    {
        kill(-pid, SIGKILL);
        corpse = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    }
    printf("PID %5d died 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
}

static void be_childish(void)
{
    /* Simulate activity on pipe */
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("Data block %d from child (%d)\n", i, (int)getpid());
    fflush(stdout);
    /* Create new pipe to coordinate between child and grandchild */
    int fd[2];
    if (pipe(fd) != 0)
        err_exit("child's pipe()");
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        err_exit("child's fork()");
    if (pid > 0)
    {
        char buffer[4];
        fprintf(stderr, "Child (%d) waiting\n", (int)getpid());
        close(fd[1]);
        read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        close(fd[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "Child (%d) exiting\n", (int)getpid());
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        _exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        /* Grandchild continues - with no standard output */
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        pid_t sid = setsid();
        fprintf(stderr, "Grandchild (%d) in session %d\n", (int)getpid(), (int)sid);
        /* Let child know grandchild has set its own session */
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        struct timespec nap = { .tv_sec = 2, .tv_nsec = 0 };
        nanosleep(&nap, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Data block %d from grandchild (%d)\n", i, (int)getpid());
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Grandchild (%d) exiting\n", (int)getpid());
    }
}

static void err_vexit(const char *fmt, va_list args)
{
    int errnum = errno;
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    if (fmt[strlen(fmt)-1] != '\n')
        putc('\n', stderr);
    if (errno != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static void err_exit(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    err_vexit(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

The functions `main()` and `be_parental()` simulate what Apache might do.  There's a pipe which becomes the standard output of the CGI child process.  The parent reads from the pipe, then sends a terminate signal to the child, and snoozes for 10 milliseconds, and then looks for a corpse.  (This is probably the least convincing part of the code, but…)  If it doesn't find one, it sends a SIGKILL signal and collects the corpse of the dead child.  It reports on how the child died and returns (and in this simulation, exits successfully).

The function `be_childish()` is the CGI child process.  It writes some output to its standard output, and flushes standard output.  It then creates a pipe so that the child and grandchild can synchronize their activity.  The child forks.  The surviving child reports that it is waiting on the grandchild, closes the write end of the pipe, reads on the read end of the pipe (for data that will never arrive, so the read will return 0 indicating EOF).  It closes the read end of the pipe, reports (on standard error) that it will exit, closes its standard output, and does exit.

Meanwhile, the grandchild closes standard output, and then makes itself into a session leader with
[`setsid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setsid.html). It reports on its new status, closes both ends of the pipe, thus releasing its parent (the orginal child process) so it can exit.  It then takes a 2-second sleep — plenty of time for the parent and grandparent to exit –
and then writes some information to standard error, an 'exiting' message and exits.

#### Sample output

```
$ ./playcgi
Data block 0 from child (60867)
Data block 1 from child (60867)
Data block 2 from child (60867)
Data block 3 from child (60867)
Data block 4 from child (60867)
Data block 5 from child (60867)
Data block 6 from child (60867)
Data block 7 from child (60867)
Data block 8 from child (60867)
Data block 9 from child (60867)
Child (60867) waiting
Grandchild (60868) in session 60868
Child (60867) exiting
PID 60867 died 0x0000
$ Data block 0 from grandchild (60868)
Data block 1 from grandchild (60868)
Data block 2 from grandchild (60868)
Data block 3 from grandchild (60868)
Data block 4 from grandchild (60868)
Data block 5 from grandchild (60868)
Data block 6 from grandchild (60868)
Data block 7 from grandchild (60868)
Data block 8 from grandchild (60868)
Data block 9 from grandchild (60868)
Grandchild (60868) exiting
```

You can hit return to enter an empty command line and get another command prompt.

There's a perceptible pause between the 'PID 60867 died 0x0000' message (and the prompt that appears) and the output of the 'Data block 0 from grandchild (60868)' message.  This shows that the child continues despite the parent dying, etc.  You can dink around with the child snoozing (so it gets signalled), or with the parent process sending signals to the process group (`kill(-pid, SIGTERM)` and `kill(-pid, SIGKILL)`), etc.  But I believe the grandchild will survive to do its writing.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try to capture `TERM` signal and ignore it until you're done processing.

Comment: Ignoring SIGTERM doesn't avoid the SIGKILL ('hard kill') that follows.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out [FastCGI](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html).  It allows you to stick closely to the CGI programming model but decouples request lifetime from process lifetime.  You could then do something like this:

```
while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0) {
    // handle normal request
    FCGI_Finish();
    // do synchronous I/O outside of request lifetime
}
```